# Passing param to ruby thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Given this snip:

```
thr = []
for n in 0..6 do
   thr[n] = Thread.new {
       print n
   }
end

for n in 0..6 do
   thr[n].join
end
```

What I would expect: `0123456`
What I get: `2220000`

The goal is to create an array of threads and wait for them each to finish. Clearly my understanding of ruby threads is lacking here.

How do I fix this?

Comment: @boulder_ruby Don't change the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pass `n` as a local variable (which has a lexical scope), but do so as a block variable.

The following code will print the numbers from `0` to `6` once each, although their order is not guaranteed.

```
thr = []
for n in 0..6 do
   thr[n] = Thread.new(n) {|n|
       print n
   }
end

for n in 0..6 do
   thr[n].join
end
```

The reason your code did not work is because the `n` within the block refers to `n` defined in `for n in 0..6`, which changes during the execution of the block. It is not that you always get `2220000`, but in many cases, you get a similar result. What the sequence of `2` at the beginning indicates is that the time it takes for `Thread.new(n)` to create a new thread and go on to execute `print n` is approximately equal to the time it takes for the `for` loop to do two iterations.

Comment: I would recommend naming the block variable differently, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Other answers may address why your code doesn't work. I will instead address myself to how to get the results you expect.

Threads do not execute in order. If you want ordered output from a series of threads, you should be using [Mutex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html), which is currently not documented for Ruby 2.3.0.

Below, I provide examples of both synchronous and asynchronous threading that provide the ordered output you're looking for. I also provide some notes on thread-safety.

### The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work

While I provide more complete examples below, the simplest solution to your problem while retaining the flavor of your original code is:

```
for n in 0..6 do Thread.new { print n }.join end
```

By using #join within the loop, you ensure that the output is ordered. This will correctly print the following to standard output:

> 0123456

### Using Mutex for Ordering Threads

Here is a more idiomatic example using [Mutex#synchronize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html#method-i-synchronize):

```
def ordered_threads
  result = ''
  (0..6).each do |n|
    Mutex.new.synchronize { result << n.to_s }
  end
  result
end

ordered_threads
#=> "0123456"
```

There's actually no need to use [Thread#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-i-join) because all threads are handled sequentially by the Mutex.

### Handling Output from Asynchronous Threads

If you don't want the overhead of using #synchronize, then you could always order your output afterwards. For example:

```
def unordered_threads
  result, threads = [], []
  (0..6).each do |n|
    threads << Thread.new { result << n.to_s }
  end
  threads.each &:join
  result.sort.join
end

unordered_threads
#=> "0123456"
```

This solution should address your posted use case, even though it is not technically thread-safe. If you need a thread-safe solution, use a Mutex or thread-safe objects like those provided by the [thread_safe](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/thread_safe) gem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tap` to create a copy of variable `n`, so modification to it in the loop does not impact the already created `Thread` objects.

```
thr = []
for n in 0..6 do
    n.tap do |n|
       thr[n] = Thread.new {
           print n
       }
    end
end

for n in 0..6 do
   thr[n].join
end
#=> 0123456
```